# Is there a way to retrieve a list of existing savepoints that have been defined in a transaction in MS SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssms

Say, I have a huge transaction with multiple save points defined at different intervals. Is there a command or tool that I can use that will provide me a list of the names of the savepoints that I have defined in my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin transaction

save transaction P1;
save transaction P2;
save transaction P3;


declare @startlsn nvarchar(23) = 
(
select min(d.database_transaction_begin_lsn)
from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions as d
join sys.dm_tran_current_transaction as c on d.transaction_id = c.transaction_id
where d.database_transaction_begin_lsn is not null
);

declare @tranId nvarchar(14) = (
select top (1) [Transaction ID]
from fn_dblog(@startlsn, @startlsn)
where @startlsn is not null
);

--save points
select [Savepoint Name], *
from fn_dblog(@startlsn, null)
where [Transaction ID] = @tranId;

rollback transaction;
```